# Updating mean and standard deviation for whole user base

Tags: python, pandas

Currently, I have data for 10,000 users with their outputs for different columns. I derive their mean and standard deviation. For this sample, I'm showing 12 categories but in a real implementation, we have close to 150 to 200 categories

df:

```
Name    mean_sd Value
cat1    mean    0.444880952
cat1    sd      0.164780194
cat2    mean    0.061
cat2    sd      0.138918315
cat3    mean    0.405407692
cat3    sd      0.197562182
cat4    mean    0.406059524
cat4    sd      0.127014912
cat5    mean    0.504
cat5    sd      0.414917047
cat6    mean    0.4865
cat6    sd      0.409555229
cat7    mean    0.436929487
cat7    sd      0.178101453
cat8    mean    0.36275
cat8    sd      0.292507261
cat9    mean    0.492371795
cat9    sd      0.182507498
cat10   mean    -1.20E-15
cat10   sd      0.560579346
cat11   mean    5.78E-16
cat11   sd      0.502121582
cat12   mean    100
cat12   sd      10.33676575
```

If I want to update for new 1000 users currently I append them to the old data and I compile with the whole database again so that I can derive a new mean and standard deviation.

code I use for calculation is as below:

```
    cat1_mean = cat1['response'].mean(axis=0)
    cat1_sd = cat1['response'].std(axis=0)
```

Now my question is, is there any better way to do this process because we are expecting to get like-new 1000,000+ user very soon. The data we get is also not a one time process, it is a gradual increase in data. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

I don't know if Stackoverflow is the right place to post this question, If not, suggest to me the right forum I will post my question over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer:

n_old = number of items in old dataframe

n_new = number of items in new dataframe

sd_old = standard deviation of old dataframe

sd_new = standard deviation of new dataframe

`on_mean_df['new_sd'] = np.sqrt(((on_mean_df['n_new']**2 * on_mean_df['sd_new'].astype(float)**2) + (on_mean_df['n_old']**2 * on_mean_df['sd_old'].astype(float)**2)) / (on_mean_df['n_new'] + on_mean_df['n_old'] ** 2))`

This gives us the new standard deviation by combing with the old data.